# HABTM via BelongsTo, possible?

Tags: cakephp, relational-database

I'm not sure how to set up a certain association.

Consider the following models: Items, Folders, Files, Owners
(this is a simplified example of something similar to what I'm trying to achieve)

Folders and Files are Items, and Items have Owners.

The database might look like this:

```
items
id, is_folder, is_file, field_common_to_folders_and_files

folders
id, item_id, special_folder_field

files
id, item_id, special_file_field

owners
id, name

items_owners
id, item_id, owner_id
```

so...

- Item hasOne Folder (if is_folder)
- Item hasOne File (if is_file)
- Item hasAndBelongsToMany Owner
- Folder belongsTo Item
- File belongesTo Item

... in the files controller:

```
$this->File->id = $id;
$data = $this->File->read();
pr($data);
```

outputs:

```
[File] => Array (
    [id] => 100
    [item_id] => 150
    [special_file_field] => 'Only files do this'
)
[Item] => Array (
    [id] => 150
    [is_folder] => 0
    [is_file] => 1
    [field_common] => 'Both folders and files do this'
)
```

...but, assuming an entry in items_owners where id=x, item_id=150, and owner_id=10, I don't get...

```
[Owner] => Array (
    0 => Array (
        [id] => 10
        [name] => 'Me'
    )
)
```

(I'd like Cake to get File->Item->Owner) Am I missing something?

Another approach I tried but am stuck with would be to define the HABTM in both Folder and File, but the item_id in the join table uses Folder's and File's id field when I need it to use the item_id field, and there doesn't seem to be an option in HABTM to override this (you can set foreignKey and associationForeignKey, but not primary keys[?]).

Of course one approach that would work would be to define the HABTM relationships in both Folder and File and create two join tables (folders_owners and files_owners), but I wanted to ask for help because 1) I have many more relationships than just owners and don't want to have 2 of each, and 2) this is bugging me because it feels like I'm missing something obvious.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synexis, you sort of answered your own question:

> "I'd like Cake to get File->Item->Owner"

I'm guessing your form for filesController is currently something like this (assuming you are using FormHelper):

```
echo $this->Form->create('File');
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('hiddenField' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('special_file_field');
echo $this->Form->input('Owner', array('multiple' => 'checkbox');
```

And in your controller:

```
$this->File->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

Instead, change the form to the following:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Item');
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('hiddenField' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('File.id', array('hiddenField' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('File.special_file_field');
echo $this->Form->input('Owner', array('multiple' => 'checkbox');
```

And in your controller:

```
$this->File->id = $id;
$file = $this->File->read();
$this->File->Item->id = $file['File']['item_id'];
$data = $this->File->Item->read();
...
$this->File->Item->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

And there you have it.

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I'll leave this question here for others.